# Linq to XML Parsing Help - getting elements?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following:

```
- <ArrayOfWsParcelDocIndexIAS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <wsParcelDocIndexIAS>
  <locatorNum xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">131312</locatorNum> 
  <docType xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">KIOOLX_DOCINDEX</docType> 
  <docID xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">234234</docID> 
  <docName xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">Document - 7/1/2008</docName> 
  <fileExists xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">true</fileExists> 
  <fileFormat xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">PDF</fileFormat> 
  </wsParcelDocIndexIAS>
- <wsParcelDocIndexIAS>
  <locatorNum xmlns="http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/">131312</locatorNum>
```

I'm trying to retrieve each element with

```
var documentElements = from docels in root.Elements("wsParcelDocIndexIAS") select docels;
```

Then

```
 foreach (XElement documentElement in documentElements)
            {
                XElement id = documentElement.Element("locatorNum");
                XElement file_type = documentElement.Element("fileFormat");
```

Yet when id and file_type are null with the syntax I'm using to try to get their values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying the namespace. Try this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/";
foreach (XElement documentElement in documentElements)
{
    XElement id = documentElement.Element(ns + "locatorNum");
    XElement file_type = documentElement.Element(ns + "fileFormat");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the XML are in the namespace `"http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/"`, but the names you give to the `Element` method are not. You need to create an [`XName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) with the [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx) and the name (there's an overloaded `+` operator for that):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://xxx/webservices/wsDocumentIndex/";
foreach (XElement documentElement in documentElements)
{
    XElement id = documentElement.Element(ns + "locatorNum");
    XElement file_type = documentElement.Element(ns + "fileFormat");
    // ...
```